Chrome Extension `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...)` connection errors
I am developing a Chrome browser extension and I have a background script that reports the status of long-running tasks to the side panel. It seems to working fine, but when I close the side panel, a bunch of errors start showing up in the debug console.

index.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.


Side panel script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const action = request.action;
    if (action === 'status-update') {
        showStatus(request.status);
    }
});

Background script
async function watchStatus(queue) {
    while(queue.running) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'status-update', status: queue.getStatus()});
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    }
};

Two questions

Is there a way to check the connection state before invoking sendMessage?

How could I suppress these errors (without swallowing other exceptions)? It does not appear to cause any issues, but all these Could not establish connection log messages make it difficult to spot actual error logs.

Also, I am assuming the chrome.runtime.sendMessage causing the error but the log has no stack trace or line number just index.js:1



Receiving end does not... ... what? and why is the error occurring so often?

You can add .catch(()=>{}) but it's better to rethink the architecture and instead of polling send a message from the side panel only when there is an actual change.

@JaromandaX the full error message is index.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

@JaromandaX "why is the error occurring so often?" - in the screenshot, it was saving a bunch of records in the background and calling chrome.runtime.sendMessage to notify the UI when each was done. But I have this same issue in a bunch of places trying to communicate from a service worker to the UI.
Also, I think there was also a catch block reporting an error occurred that doubled the output. The screenshot was of the most egregious-looking console output.

@wOxxOm It is not polling from the UI. The issue is when the background process sends a message, and the panel is closed.

@wOxxOm adding .catch(()=>{}) to the chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...) does the trick. I was using try/catch blocks in some places, but that seemed to have no effect. Good catch!
After seeing that error scroll through, I expected there to be a method like chrome.runtime.hasListeners() or some way to check before sending a message – but I cannot find anything in the documentation.

You can use chrome.runtime.getContexts, but catch() is simpler.
